# alternatives to nested for loops and PANDAS

Tags: python, pandas

I have two dataframes and want to allocate the data in one data frame to another. The only approach that I can think of is a nested for loop. With large data sets, this approach takes way to long. I was wondering if anyone had any ideas how to improve performance. My code looks something like this:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
def make_merge(df1,df2):
    df3=pd.DataFrame(columns=["ID","Depot","Allocated Amt1"])
    for id1,amt1 in list(zip(df1["ID"],df1["Amt1"])):
        found=False
        amt = amt1
        for id2,Depot,amt2 in list (zip(df2["ID"],df2["Depot"],df2["Amt2"])): 
            if ( id1==id2):
                found = True
                if amt- amt2 > 0:
                    try:
                        df3.loc[-1]=[id1,Depot,amt2]
                        df3.index = df3.index+1
                        df3=df3.sort_index()
                    except:
                        df3.loc[-1]=[id1,np.nan,amt2]
                        df3.index = df3.index+1
                        df3=df3.sort_index()
                    amt-=amt2
                else:
                    try:
                        df3.loc[-1]=[id1,Depot,amt]
                        df3.index = df3.index +1
                        df3=df3.sort_index()
                    except:
                        df3.loc[-1]=[id1,np.nan,amt]
                        df3.index = df3.index +1
                        df3=df3.sort_index()
                    amt=0
        if amt >0:
            if found:
                df3.loc[-1]=[id1,"not fully allocated",amt]
                df3.index=df3.index+1
                df3=df3.sort_index()
    return(df3.sort_values(by="ID"))
```

The input and output look something like this:

```
df1= pd.DataFrame({'ID':['A','B'],'Amt1':[10,20]})
df2= pd.DataFrame({'ID':['A','B','A'],'Depot':['DTC','BNY','BNY'],'Amt2':[5,10,5]})
c=make_merge(df1,df2)
c
```

the input and output tables look like this:
[image]

Comment: Have you tried using the built-in `merge` functionality that Pandas offers?

Comment: yup. tried using merge. however, since the allocation logic is a bit complex, I had to resort to for loops

Comment: What does your output `c` look like?

Comment: So do I understand it correctly that you need to add a "not fully allocated" entry to `Depot` if there is a depot missing in `df2`? Other than that you just need to merge difference `Amt1` and `Amt2`?

Comment: the total in df1 always needs to be maintained. If df2<df1, i need to create a dummy record called "not fully allocated"

Answer (score 1):

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'ID': ['A', 'B'], 'Amt1': [10, 20]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'ID': ['A', 'B', 'A'], 'Depot': ['DTC', 'BNY', 'BNY'], 'Amt2': [5, 10, 5]})

# calculate allocated
df_a = pd.merge(df1, df2, how="right", on="ID")
df_a["Allocated Amt1"] = df_a["Amt2"]
df_a = df_a[["ID", "Depot", "Allocated Amt1"]]

# calulate not allocated
df_totals = df2.groupby("ID").sum()
df_na = pd.merge(df1, df_totals, on="ID")
df_na["Allocated Amt1"] = df_na["Amt1"] - df_na["Amt2"]
df_na = df_na[df_na["Allocated Amt1"] > 0]
df_na["Depot"] = "not fully allocated"
df_na = df_na[["ID", "Depot", "Allocated Amt1"]]

# concatenate
df_final = pd.concat([df_a, df_na], axis=0)
print(df_final)
```